# How does one deal with linear regression with heteroscedasticity?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, linear-model, overdispersion

Suppose I have a dataset with outcome continuous. I applied various transformations on either covariate, outcome or both. I have also tried polynomial terms. I always get over heteroscedasticity when looking at scale location plot. I also find regression coefficient significant which might be due to heteroscedasticity.

How do I handle heteroscedasticity issue in linear regression?

What kind of distribution family for error term should be considered here in general?

Comment: Most suggestions might have would be difficult to make without a clear idea what form the heteroskedasticity might take. What does the response variable measure? What did you see in the plot?

Comment: @Glen_b The response is measure of log of cost of services.(Cost of service is always >0 which is skewed. So $log(x+c)$ for some $0<c<1$ will make it less skewed.) The scale location plot shows quadratic behavior of fitted values. Should I consider residual weighted regression instead?

Comment: @user45765 dealing with heteroscedasticity is a very general problem. There is not a single answer possible for this. The standard approach, like least squares fitting, indeed assumes iid gaussian distributed error terms, and this is violated in your case. When this is violated then you might consider a different model. But, what model... that depends a lot of the situation. You need to explain this further. What mechanism are you studying (are there any previously known relationships for this type of data) and how does it look like (show your plots in the question).

Comment: In addition... the violation of the assumptions of least squares fitting, whether this matters (and how you deal with it) depends on what you are doing with it.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Is there any reference on dealing heteroscedasticity? I felt this is least covered in most statistics books I have seen.

Comment: @user45765 the way that I deal with heteroscedasticity is often by using an [ab initio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ab_initio) approach and model the variance in some way (or at least have some approximate idea about it). But if you are in a scientific/technical field where you have no clue about the variance, then you could use some approximate function. I don't think there is a single good answer to this general problem.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I think I will have to determine the variance as a function of response(hopefully) and then figure out whether I am allowed to use sandwich estimator for the variance. Then perform linear contrast tests. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: 1. Most important is to get the relationship between the variables in your model to be approximately right; in particular if your transformation makes it less linear you may be worse off.  2. When you say quadratic, was the relationship increasing, decreasing or was there a turning point inside the range of the data? 3. It sounds very much that an approximate approach may be needed. 4. Given there's a clear mean-variance relationship, my first thought would not be as general a sandwich estimator, but it's certainly one approach.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks a lot for suggestions.